# Data Projection in the Future

Tags: prediction, finance

Suppose we have the following data:

```
               begin date     end date   quantity
                 10/01/13      01/06/14      5
                 01/07/14      01/01/2015    7.5
                 01/02/2015    07/03/2015    10.67
```

The average difference between end dates is about 0.5 years. I want to project the future quantities using the average difference between end dates. I have something like the following:

```
                  begin date     end date   quantity
                 10/01/13      01/06/14      5
                 01/07/14      01/01/2015    7.5
                 01/02/2015    07/03/2015    10.67
                 07/04/2015    01/02/2016 
                 01/03/2016    07/03/2016       
                 07/04/2016    01/02/2017 
                 01/03/2017    07/04/2017
```

The end dates were determined by adding 0.5 years (~182 days) to the start dates. Is there any good way of getting the four future projections for quantity?

Could I look at the percentage increase in quantity based on end dates:

$$ \frac{\frac{7.5-5}{5}}{\text{time between 01/06/14 and 01/01/2015}}$$
$$                                 \vdots $$

and somehow apply that?

Answer (score 1):

So many things can go wrong with this prediction that I hesitate to answer.

If we look at Quantity per day we get .05 for the first period, .02 for the second period, .06 for the third period, and .04 overall. Note we don't have enough information to estimate trend or determine seasonality.

Lacking any knowledge of the underlying data generation mechanism, I would retreat to a simple average forecast and assume .04 per day for all future periods.  For 182 days, this would be 6.6.

Comment: +1 You might add that a huge standard error of estimate is attached to your forecast!

Comment: @whuber: So we can't use any type of time series? Only if we had more data?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand either of those questions. As this answer by zbicyclist points out, you have little information, and therefore any projection you make is going to be highly uncertain. Whether that uncertainty decreases with more data depends on how they vary; whether it decreases with different kinds of data depends on the nature of the new data. Statistical procedures are not magic: they cannot manufacture new information. At best, they provide useful insight into the implications of your data and the assumptions you make about them. Part of that is quantifying the uncertainty.